# How would I implement a following drone with a camera using GPS?

Tags: cameras, gps, line-following

As the title states, is there any way to make a following drone that tracks a GPS unit, and follows/orients camera to that? Similar to [this](https://www.lily.camera/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you will have GPS on your drone in addition to the GPS unit you will want to track.

You will make heavy use of the [Haversine formula](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), which will tell you the bearing between 2 lat/lon (GPS) coordinates.  This will come in handy in the following ways:

1. Using the current and previous coordinates from the target's GPS, you know what direction the target is moving.
2. Using the drone's coordinates and target's coordinates, you know what direction to aim the camera.

Once you know where the target is and what your orientation should be to it, you can calculate the drone's desired position based on the desired following distance.

Comment: Fantastic answer. However, I forgot to mention that I know nothing about RC in general...how would I relay this to my not-yet-existent drone? What modules would I need?

Comment: You should ask this question separately after you have a drone -- until then, it's too broad for anyone to give you a good answer.